# 2 pane crud table view for nested table (main and detail table)

Tags: javascript, datatables

Would someone have an example how to create 2 tables in i.e. Javascript.

One table at the top of the web page. This table  is the master table and one table is rendered at the bottom of the web page which is a detail table from the record currently selected in the master table. Both tables need to be able to perform crud operations.

Use case:

A table or customer invoices displays customer name, invoice number, invoice date and total amount.

When the customer row is clicked in the master table the second table (detail table) renders the details of the invoice such as items purchased that pertain to that invoice,price, quantity etc. with a total price at the bottom that matches the net value of the invoice master table.

Maybe there is a way to do it with jquery or datatables. Data should be loaded and manipulated via REST calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will suites your senario:

```
    $('#maintable').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "searching": true,
        "scrollY": 'calc(100vh - 300px)',
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "ajax": {
            "url": "//urlformaintabledata",
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": "json",
            "data": function (filtersDto) {
                //input data goes here
            },
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                name: "referenceno",
                data: "ReferenceNo",
                title: "ReferenceNo",
                orderable: true,
            },

            //other column list here

            {
                name: "CreatedDate",
                data: "CreatedDateString",
                title: "Details",
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<button  data-detail_id="row.id"> </button>';
                },
                orderable: true
            },
        ],
    })

    $('#btn_details_id').on('click',function(){
        var id =$(this).data('detail_id');
        $('#detailtable').DataTable({
            "serverSide": true,
            "processing": true,
            "searching": true,
            "scrollY": 'calc(100vh - 300px)',
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "ajax": {
                "url": "//url_for_details/id",
                "type": "POST",
                "dataType": "json",
                "data": function (filtersDto) {

                    //input data goes here
                },
            },
        })
    })
```

Comment: @Kevin Keller Is this helpfull to you?

Comment: Sorry i just came back to this project now. Very helpful indeed. Thank you!!